# How to run NanoHttp daemon as OS service on MacOS?

Tags: macos, service, nanohttpd

I have a custom application made with nanohttp daemon to control a local printer using a rest API.

I could make its OS service installer for Windows using Apache commons daemon, but I'm stuck while doing the same for macOS. How can I create a OS service in a mac of a java application?

Answer (score 0):

To create a macOS service for your Java application, you can use launchd, which is the system-wide service management framework in macOS. Here's a basic outline of the steps you'll need to follow:

Create a Launchd Property List (plist) file: This file describes your service to launchd.

Install the plist file in the correct directory: Usually, this is /Library/LaunchDaemons/ for system-wide services or ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ for user-specific services.

Load the service: Use launchctl to load the service into launchd.